Passing a variable from a class in one file to a class in another file
I am trying to pass variables from a class in one variable to a class in another. The variable I am trying to access is in the class called LoginOrReg in a file called LoginOrReg. I am trying to use the login_username and data variables. I have tried From LoginOrReg import * but that doesnt seem to work.
Here is my code as it stands
class LoginOrReg:

    customtkinter.set_appearance_mode('dark')
    customtkinter.set_default_color_theme('blue')
    

    def __init__(self, db, cursor, login_username, data):
        self.db = mysql.connector.connect(host = '', user = '', password= '', database="")
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
        self.login_username = login_username
        self.data = data
  #provides the login screen where the user is asked for an existing username and password
    def login(self):
        self.login_window = customtkinter.CTk()
        self.login_window.geometry('400x400')
        self.login_username_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.login_window, placeholder_text ='Enter Your Username')
        self.login_username_entry.pack(pady=30)
        self.login_username = self.login_username_entry.get() 
        self.login_password_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(self.login_window, placeholder_text ='Enter Your Password')
        self.login_password_entry.pack(pady=30)
        self.login_password = self.login_password_entry.get()
        self.log_user_in_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.login_window, text = 'Login', command = self.log_user_in).pack(pady=30)
        self.reg_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.login_window, text = 'Register New User', command = self.reg_user).pack(pady=20)
        self.login_window.mainloop()

    #Logs the user in
    def log_user_in(self):
        self.habit = HT.HabitTracker(main_window=' ', sorting_options= ' ', sort= ' ', login= ' ')
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT username AND password, COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=%s AND password=%s GROUP BY username',(self.login_username_entry.get(), self.login_password_entry.get()))
        self.cursor.fetchall()
        self.row_count = self.cursor.rowcount
        if self.row_count == 1:
            self.cursor.execute('SELECT userID FROM users WHERE username=%s AND password=%s',(self.login_username_entry.get(), self.login_password_entry.get()))
            self.data = self.cursor.fetchone()
            print(self.data)
            self.user_id = self.data[0]
            self.habit.main_menu(LoginOrReg)
        else:
            self.my_label = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.login_window, text = "User Not Found. Please Try Again.", font=('Helvetica', 10)).pack(pady=10)


login_reg = LoginOrReg(db = " ", cursor=" ", login_username= ' ', data = ' ')
login_reg.login_or_reg(root=" ")

I am trying to call the login_username and data variable to a Class called HabitTracker in a file called HabitTracker. The code runs but it seems the assigned value of the variables are not carried through. Here is where I try to access the variables in the HabitTracker file.
from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector
import customtkinter
import math
from datetime import datetime
from LoginOrReg import *


class HabitTracker:
    def __init__(self, main_window, sorting_options, sort, login) -> None:
        self.main_window = main_window 
        self.db = mysql.connector.connect(host = '', user = '', password= '', database="")
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
        self.sorting_options = sorting_options
        self.sort = sort 
        self.login = login
        
    def main_menu(self, LR):
        import LoginOrReg as LR
        self.login = LR.LoginOrReg(db=' ', cursor= ' ', login_username=' ', data= ' ')
        self.date = datetime.today()
        self.main_window = customtkinter.CTk()
        self.main_window.geometry('1080x720')
        self.sorting_options = ['Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly', 'Highest Streak',]
        self.mylabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.main_window, text='Welcome {}'.format(self.login.login_username), font=('Arial', 40)).pack(pady=5)
        self.sort = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(self.main_window, values= self.sorting_options, command= sort_by.sort_by)
        self.sort.set('Sort By')
        self.sort.pack(pady=10)
        self.create_new_habit_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.main_window, text='Create New Habit', command=create_habit.create_habit, fg_color='green').pack(pady=20)
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT habit_name FROM habit WHERE user_id=%s GROUP BY habit_name', (self.login.data,))
        self.habits = self.cursor.fetchall()
        self.j = 0
        for j in self.habits:
            self.habit_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.main_window, text=self.habits[self.j], command=lambda k = self.habits[self.j]: edit_habit.edit_habit(k))
            self.habit_button.pack(pady=10)
            self.j = self.j + 1
        self.main_window.mainloop()  

as you can see I have tried to create an object in the method, called login and then accessing the variables by doing
self.login.data

this method does not work.

Show how you're calling HabitTracker. If self.login is a LoginOrReg instance, self.login.data should work.

Why are you reassigning self.login in main_menu()? You already assigned it in __init__().

Thank you. I have removed my intialization of self.login in the init() method. I also thought that my code should work. But where i want it to display the usersname in my main menu there is nothing. It doesnt look as if it actually has the same values as the values assigned in LoginOrReg.

from tkinter import *
import mysql.connector
import customtkinter
import math
from datetime import datetime
from LoginOrReg import *


class HabitTracker:
    def __init__(self, main_window, sorting_options, sort, login) -> None:
        self.main_window = main_window 
        self.db = mysql.connector.connect(host = '', user = '', password= '', database="")
        self.cursor = self.db.cursor()
        self.sorting_options = sorting_options
        self.sort = sort 
        self.login = login
        
    def main_menu(self, LR):
        import LoginOrReg as LR
        self.login = LR.LoginOrReg(db=' ', cursor= ' ', login_username=' ', data= ' ')
        self.date = datetime.today()
        self.main_window = customtkinter.CTk()
        self.main_window.geometry('1080x720')
        self.sorting_options = ['Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly', 'Highest Streak',]
        self.mylabel = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self.main_window, text='Welcome {}'.format(self.login.login_username), font=('Arial', 40)).pack(pady=5)
        self.sort = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(self.main_window, values= self.sorting_options, command= sort_by.sort_by)
        self.sort.set('Sort By')
        self.sort.pack(pady=10)
        self.create_new_habit_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.main_window, text='Create New Habit', command=create_habit.create_habit, fg_color='green').pack(pady=20)
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT habit_name FROM habit WHERE user_id=%s GROUP BY habit_name', (self.login.data,))
        self.habits = self.cursor.fetchall()
        self.j = 0
        for j in self.habits:
            self.habit_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(self.main_window, text=self.habits[self.j], command=lambda k = self.habits[self.j]: edit_habit.edit_habit(k))
            self.habit_button.pack(pady=10)
            self.j = self.j + 1
        self.main_window.mainloop()


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Don't just post code. Explain what's wrong in the OP's code, and how you fixed it in your code.
